RTK Query vs middleware
Is RTK Query a middleware ?
What is the difference between RTK Query and middleware in redux toolkit.
As per redux toolkit documentation its seen that RTK Query is used to handle side effects like data fetching. If so then why do you need a middleware like redux-thunk or saga ?


Is RTK Query a middleware?

No, Redux-Toolkit's Query module is an abstraction built over RTK slices, e.g. it is an API slice that generates actions and reducers, middleware to add to the store, and if you opt-in, React hooks for ease-of-use. The state it maintains is that of the endpoint metadata, i.e. the queries/mutations made and their cached results.

What is the difference between RTK Query and middleware in redux toolkit.

The above briefly explains this. Middleware are an "extension point between dispatching an action, and the moment it reaches the reducer", and are one component of the larger feature set that comprises the RTK-Query module. In simple terms middleware is how Redux can "issue side-effects" outside the realm of dispatched actions and pure reducer functions.

As per redux toolkit documentation its seen that RTK Query is used to handle side effects like data fetching. If so then why do you need a middleware like redux-thunk or saga?

You really don't need them if using Redux-Toolkit and RTK-Query. RTK ships with the Thunk middleware included and enabled by default, so there's already no need to integrate Redux-Thunk, and Saga's haven't been the recommended way to issue side-effects in React projects for at least several years now, maybe longer.
Similar to how RTK eliminates a ton of boilerplate Redux code and RTK's createAsyncAction generates the pending, fulfilled, and rejected actions, RTKQ builds upon this the query/mutation loading/data/error statuses and maintains a cache of fetched results. It's an über-abstraction/optimization to manage fetching and caching data client-side.
